# Create product of lists, concatenated, in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
import itertools
x = [[0,0],[1,1]]
list(itertools.product(x,x))
```

produces

```
[([0, 0], [0, 0]), ([0, 0], [1, 1]), ([1, 1], [0, 0]), ([1, 1], [1, 1])]
```

But I'm looking for something that produces

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you can easily do without using `itertools`, using list comprehension:

```
x = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
output = [a + b for b in x for a in x]
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

the equivalent without list comprehension would be:

```
output = []
for a in x:
    for b in x:
        output.append(a + b)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.product` is giving you that answer, you just have to concatenate the lists

```
[a + b for a, b in [([0, 0], [0, 0]), ([0, 0], [1, 1]), ([1, 1], [0, 0]), ([1, 1], [1, 1])]]
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.reshape` if you are considering numpy array.

```
np.reshape(list(itertools.product(x,x)),(4,4))
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```